# Win32API+Direct2Dでの高DPI環境での不具合について

Tags: windows, winapi, directx, mingw, dpi

## 前置き

Visual Studio 2017でWin32API+Direct2Dのアプリケーションを作っていて高DPIで描画させたいと思いました．
そこでHWNDが初期化される前にSetProcessDpiAwarenessContext関数を，引数をDPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWAREとして呼び出しました．私の環境では，DPIに対してUnawareならばGetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX),GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX)の戻り値が96となり，System awareだった場合192となります．

## 発生した問題

D2D1::RenderTargetPropertiesのDPIの値をこれらの値で初期化した時，96であれば問題なくDirect2Dが働いて描画されるのですが，DPIが192だった場合描画されなくなるのです．MinGW 8.1.0で同じようにSetProcessDpiAwarenessContextを呼び出した場合DPIが192であっても描画されるのですが，Visual Studioで作成した場合描画されなくなります．
ネットで調べたのですがこのような事例が見当たらず．．．
MinGWで動いて，Visual Studioで動かないということはSDKの問題なのかもしれません．

とにかく，どのようにすればDirect2Dを用いて高DPIで描画できるのでしょうか．
よろしくお願いいたします．

## 環境

Windows 10 64ビット(バージョン：1903，OSビルド：18362.959)
Visual Studio 2017　（問題が発生した環境）
MinGW 8.1.0　     　（問題が発生しなかった環境）

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ [Displaying properly on a high-DPI display](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to--size-a-window-properly-for-high-dpi-displays), [Direct2D and High-DPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-and-high-dpi)

Comment: `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE` とのことですが、正しくテストできているか確認させてください。現在はPer Monitor V2で動作しており、System aware自体エミュレーションされています（GetDeviceCapsの戻り値を含め）。DPIスケーリングをSystem awareに完全に適用させるためにはOS再起動が必要です。きちんと再起動を行ってから表示確認されていますでしょうか？

Comment: 質問の投稿主です．WindowsのDPIに関しては疎くて，ネットでアプリケーションを高DPI化する方法を調べてたどり着いた方法でした．改めてDPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2に設定したところ，やはりDirect2Dによる描画はウィンドウに反映されていないようでした．